# Question on definition on row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

When looking at the definition for echelon form, it says

1. All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeros
2. Each leading entry of a row is in a column strictly to the right of the leading entry of the row above it
3. All entries in a column below a leading entry are zeros.

It seems to me that the first two properties automatically imply the third. So is the third one redundant in definition? Thanks

Comment: Presumably, "leading entry" should be "leading non-zero entry".  If so, then yes: the third condition is redundant.

Comment: The likely reason that the third condition ended up in the list is that it contrasts nicely to the third condition required in the definition of *reduced* row-echelon form, where we require the entries above the leading entry to be zero as well.

Comment: Yes，leading entry is the leftmost nonzero element. Thanks for the very insightful explanation!